# Print text from terminal

Tags: command-line, printing

I would like to use a Linux distro without a desktop environment, but I need to print out homework that I type up.

I could always email it to myself and print from another computer, but it would be nice if I could just do something like `print homework.txt` from a bash prompt. Does anyone have a way of doing this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

CUPS understands many different types of files directly, including text, PostScript, PDF, and image files. This allows you to print from inside your applications or at the command-line, whichever is most convenient! Type either of the following commands to print a file to the default (or only) printer on the system:

```
lp filename 
lpr filename
```

Use the `-d` option with the `lp` command to print to a specific printer:

```
lp -d printer filename
```

Or the `-P` option with the `lpr` command:

```
lpr -P printer filename
```

Printing the Output of a Program

Both the `lp` and `lpr` commands support printing from the standard input:

```
program | lp
program | lp -d printer
program | lpr
program | lpr -P printer
```

If the program does not provide any output, then nothing will be queued for printing.

More advanced options can be added to the print job with the `-o` [options](https://csl.cs.wisc.edu/services/printing). For exampling stapling:

```
lpr -P printer -o StapleLocation=UpperLeft
```

[Source and more Details.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160621112413/http://www.eecs.utk.edu/resources/it/kb/printing/linux-command-line)

Answer (score 5):

Last time I was using such a system, I used to prefer `enscript`. It's been a while but I seem to recall it being a more sophisticated version of `lpr` which could do everything that `lpr` did and then some. It works like so:

```
enscript foo.file
```

It can either print directly to a printer or convert text to postscript. It should be available in the repositories of all major distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

I chose to install Manjaro "Full" which includes printer networking and printing support. From past experience, the "Minimal" install requires a non-trivial amount of effort to get anything printed.

I didn't know the name of my printer. I tried `lpstat -t` but that showed the following:

```
scheduler is running
no system default destination
lpstat: No destinations added.
lpstat: No destinations added.
lpstat: No destinations added.
lpstat: No destinations added.
```

At first, I was able to get lpstat working by connecting through Geany, but the printer would timeout after a few minutes.

Since I have a relatively new printer, it uses the "IPP" standard. I used `ippfind -l` thanks to this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490827/8234

For me the address was ipp://whatever.local:631/ipp/print

Then I found this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/683993/8234 and that worked great `lpadmin -p Cool -v ipp://whatever.local:631/ipp/print -m everywhere`

Now `lpstat -t` works as expected:

> Cool accepting requests since Sun 19 Mar 2023 02:23:37 AM CDT printer
> Cool is idle.  enabled since Sun 19 Mar 2023 02:23:37 AM CDT

Then I can simply do `echo "test" | lp -d Cool`

PS: Perhaps there is an easier way. You can try `ippfind -s` and then change the spaces to underscores like `echo "test" | lp -d Canon_Cool_series` but I can't get this to work without the underscores, and I can't find any documentation explaining why this works. Basically, I cheated by activating the printer through Geany, and then I could see the printer with `lpstat -t`

For future reference, I would try the easier "underscore" method first, and if that times out or doesn't work, use the longer "lpadmin" method.