# Why does Avahi see my network printer but CUPS doesn't?

Tags: arch-linux, cups, avahi

I've set up [.local hostname resolution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Avahi#Hostname_resolution), [started cups-browsed](https://github.com/l0b0/root/blob/474ff12fdfae4e4a4af1675561692d34d8c68b1f/modules/printing_system/manifests/init.pp) and [restarted org.cups.cupsd.service](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS#Network). `avahi-browse` shows the WiFi printer:

```
$ avahi-browse --all --ignore-local | head --lines=1 | tr --squeeze-repeats ' '
+ enp5s0 IPv6 Canon MG6400 series _canon-bjnp1._tcp local
```

However, http://127.0.0.1:631/admin/ shows no printers whatsoever. What gives?

Answer (score 7):

<sub>WARNING: This answer in its totality is only valid for more recent versions of CUPS (like 2.2.x). For previous versions, ask specifically if you do not understand what the manpage for *cupsd.conf* says...</sub>

---

***First***, CUPS only ever automatically installs and detects local network printers which announce themselves as IPP-capable (*Internet Printing Protocol*). A proprietary Canon-designed protocol will not work.

To check if your printer is one of the IPP-enabled models, simply run

```
ippfind [ENTER]
```

It should return a list of print device (or CUPS queue) URIs which are IPP-enabled.

***Second***, if your Canon MG6400 model ***did*** support IPP, your avahi-browse discovery should be returning not simply the service subtype `_canon-bjnp1._tcp`, but also `_ipp._tcp.` and/or `_ipps._tcp.` .... but maybe you are overlooking this, because your `| head --lines=1` throws these results out of the window?

***Third***, to enable CUPS for full participation in ZeroConf/Bonjour networking to automatically use shared printers and in turn share its own local printers, you need the following lines in your */etc/cups/cupsd.conf* file:

```
BrowseDNSSDSubTypes _cups,_print
BrowseLocalProtocols all
Port 631
```

Comment: +1 for the ippfind command, so helpful in diagnosing my problem!

Answer (score 2):

For automatic discovery, you need an extra component from CUPS called `cups-browsed`, which queries the Avahi daemon and then populates CUPS configuration based on what the Avahi daemon sees.  Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure what's needed on Arch to get this set up (the daemon itself shouldn't need any customization to the configuration, I'm just not sure what the service name is on Arch to enable it, or even whether it's part of the standard CUPS install or not).

Comment: That's already installed & running.

Comment: There are so many "wrongs" with this answer, I don't even...